# Creating a website that displays flashcards

Tags: javascript

I am looking to make a flashcard website a little like quizlet but also that has a portion where you can type in words to spell with pronunciations. How can I go about this plan?

Comment: Welcome To StackOverflow! Your question is **VERY** broad, making it off-topic for StackOverflow. Break your task down into individual steps, [**attempt each step**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), then come back with a **specific** problem you encountered. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. I use an app called Wappalyzer in my firefox browser (addon). if i go to quizlet and run it, it shows several different technologies, React being one of them. This is a fairly advanced framework for JavaScript and will no doubt take some time to learn.

I would recommend learning it (as i am currently trying to learn React) but i the mean time using something more basic. You might look into modal windows with CSS or check out some css animations where you can resize containers. You might even get the card effect by using css shadowing. this is a great site to learn all this css stuff. https://www.w3schools.com/

jquery is pretty easy to get started with as long as you have a basic understanding of javascript, and has some great animations that you could simulate flashcards with.

I've used Wix as well, and many programmers will be reluctant to use CMS, but it has some cool front end features is you are new to HTML & CSS, and it has a really cool backend which runs node and has module support, allows JS on the front end, and even has a bunch of really cool jQuery type APIs. its a great place to start and because it has a programming layer, you can grow with it.

good luck!